# How to get the life cycle status of the instances in OCI cloud?

Tags: python, sdk, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get the life cycle state of the resources or instances via API call.

There are API calls via group wise and I couldn't find a single API call to get the life cycle state. Am I missing something here or going in a wrong way?

Any suggestions to get all the resources life cycle state in a single API call?

Have seen different API calls like `list_categories` and here is the code:

```
list_categories_response = optimizer_client.list_categories(
    compartment_id='ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaau2ommhsjq2vocet4e6nz3p76gefajqcjjxrj2x2ovvllexyey7ja',
    compartment_id_in_subtree=True,
    include_organization=True,
    sort_order="ASC",
    sort_by="NAME",
    lifecycle_state="DELETED",
    )
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
self.raise_transient_service_error(request, response, service_code, message, operation_name, api_reference_link, target_service, request_endpoint, client_version, timestamp, deserialized_data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oci/base_client.py", line 892, in raise_transient_service_error
    raise exceptions.TransientServiceError(
oci.exceptions.TransientServiceError: {'target_service': 'optimizer', 'status': 500, 'code': 'InternalError', 'opc-request-id': '5EB910E3EB1B4493B4ED444AB0A28DF3/66BA242702176FFB8B1DEB08DCA2D9F9/A2BEC1E908F38A745C4E79555C630313', 'message': 'Internal error occurred', 'operation_name': 'list_categories', 'timestamp': '2023-12-14T04:27:31.668993+00:00', 'client_version': 'Oracle-PythonSDK/2.118.0', 'request_endpoint': 'GET https://optimizer.ap-hyderabad-1.oci.oraclecloud.com/20200606/categories', 'logging_tips': 'To get more info on the failing request, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/latest/logging.html for ways to log the request/response details.', 'troubleshooting_tips': "See https://docs.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/References/apierrors.htm#apierrors_500__500_internalerror for more information about resolving this error. Also see https://docs.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/advisor/20200606/CategorySummary/ListCategories for details on this operation's requirements. If you are unable to resolve this optimizer issue, please contact Oracle support and provide them this full error message."}
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitu
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but if you only have a small number of things like "instances" the best is to use the Search service.

From the CLI:

```
$ oci search resource structured-search --query-text 'query instance resources'
```

The result will be a list of all of the compute instances along with their lifecycle state (lifecycle-state)

```
        "display-name": "instance90210",
        "freeform-tags": {},
        "identifier": "ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.XXX",
        "identity-context": {},
        "lifecycle-state": "Stopped",
        "resource-type": "Instance",
```

The search syntax allows you to do all sorts of interesting things like query for a specific type of resource or for all resources with a specific "lifecycleState".

And obviously, you can do the same with the Python SDK.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do this using the python sdk calls.

Comment: Search is part of the OCI SDK. In fact the CLI is implemented in Python and in many cases a just a thin layer over them.

You want to look at [ResourceSearchClient](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/resource_search/client/oci.resource_search.ResourceSearchClient.html) and the example there.